# Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

Application:Windows Service .NET Framework 4.6.2
Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ:1.7.2.4108

The program periodically closes the connection and reconnects. I don’t know why an out-of-memory error occurs when connecting.

When an error occurs there is a small chance that it will succeed all of a sudden, but usually the same error persists.

I would like to ask why and how to solve it?

exception:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: 
在 System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal(IPrincipal principal, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
在 System.Threading.Thread.Start(StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
在 System.Threading.Thread.Start() 
在 Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Threads.DedicatedTaskRunner..ctor(Task task, String taskName, ThreadPriority taskPriority) 
在 Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Threads.TaskRunnerFactory.CreateTaskRunner(Task task, String name, ThreadPriority taskPriority) 
在 Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Threads.TaskRunnerFactory.CreateTaskRunner(Task task, String name)
在 Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Threads.TaskRunnerFactory.CreateTaskRunner(Task task) 
在 Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.SessionExecutor.Wakeup() 
在 Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.MessageConsumer.Start() 
在 Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Session.Start() 
在 Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Connection.Start()
```

connection:

```
Connecter objConnecter = new Connecter();
objConnecter._TargetServer = strQueueServer;
objConnecter._TargetQueue = strResponseMSGQueue;

IConnectionFactory objFactory = new NMSConnectionFactory(new Uri("activemq:tcp://" + strQueueServer + ":61616"));
var objConnection = objFactory.CreateConnection();
objConnection.ClientId = strResponseMSGQueue;

objConnecter._objConnection = objConnection;

ISession objSession;
objSession = objConnection.CreateSession();
objConnecter._objSession = objSession;
objConnecter._strSystemName = SystemName;

IDestination objDestination;

if (strActiveMQ_Type == 1)
    objDestination = objSession.GetTopic(strResponseMSGQueue);
else
    objDestination = objSession.GetQueue(strResponseMSGQueue);
objConnecter._objDestination = objDestination;

IMessageConsumer objConsumer;
objConsumer = objSession.CreateConsumer(objDestination, null, false);
objConnecter._objMessageConsumer = objConsumer;

listConnecters.Add(objConnecter);

objConsumer.Listener += objConnecter.OnListener;
objConnection.Start();
```

disconnection:

```
obj._objConnection.Stop();
obj._objMessageConsumer.Listener -= obj.OnListener;
obj._objMessageConsumer.Close();
obj._objMessageConsumer.Dispose();
obj._objDestination.Dispose();
obj._objSession.Close();
obj._objSession.Dispose();
obj._objConnection.Close();
obj._objConnection.Dispose();
```

Comment: You'd need to use whatever memory debug tooling MS has provided you to figure out what is consuming your memory, folks here can't really guess at what that might be.